# Test Class for VF page controller - accessed via list view button - no inputs

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

Need some help. I know how to create test class for a apex class that expects inputs. How do you create a test class for a controller that is just performing a query and has no inputs?

Here is my controller:

```
public class CongaReportController {

    String APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX = 'APXTConga4';

    public List<user> getCongaUsers() {

        List<User> results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Name FROM User ' + 
            'WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserId FROM UserPackageLicense WHERE (PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX)) ' +
            'ORDER BY Name ASC'
        );
        return results;

    }
}
```

The VF Page

```
<apex:page Controller="CongaReportController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Conga Licensed Users">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CongaUsers}" var="LIC">
            <apex:column value="{!LIC.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

As stated in title, this page is accessed via a Related list View button.

So how do I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can test (based on the code) is the number of users returned by the method `getCongaUsers()` (negative/positive). In general your test class could look like this (simplified example):

```
CongaReportController con = new CongaReportController();
System.assertEquals(XX, con.getCongaUsers());
```

BUT you might want to prepare a test data first. Based on the code provided it could be the following objects:

- User
- UserPackageLicense

So the complete test class looks then like this:

```
Create User
Insert User
Create UserPackageLicense and associate it with User-Id
Insert UserPackageLicense

CongaReportController con = new CongaReportController();
System.assertEquals(XX, con.getCongaUsers());
```

Comment: If I follow your second suggestion am I supposed to put in 1 for the XX value of your assert statement? I will have more licensed users than that so I am not sure I am interpreting your code correctly.

Comment: mocked `UserPackageLicense` is going to have to be associated to `PackageLicense` with namespacePrefix = 'APXTConga4'. `PackageLicense` does not need to be mocked in the testmethod as they are visible even with `SeeAllData=false`. Then, XX = 1. Best practice would be to make `APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX` @TestVisible so testmethod uses same constant to query for the Conga package as is used by prod code

Comment: @MattM It is a best practice to NOT access a real data from a test class, that's why I've "created" a new user record. Since it is the only record available (assuming you are using SeeAllData=false) - you should set 1 to the assertion function (the method SHOULD return only one record, otherwise it will fail).